# nodejs docker build ERROR (failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB)?

Tags: node.js, docker

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-stretch
```

cmd

```
C:\Users\Kirill\drp>docker build -t krll/cheknum:beta2 .
[+] Building 3.6s (5/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12-stretch                                           2.0s
 => ERROR [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12-stretch                                                             1.4s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:12-stretch                                                                   1.4s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 3.60kB                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12-stretch:
------
------
 > [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12-stretch:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

ver

```
C:\Users\Kirill\drp>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.2
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:00:27 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:07:04 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsHSe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iTQu.png)